# anchor not working with iphone mail body

Tags: c#, html, ios, vb.net, outlook

i have an email service that generates approval emails with certain information and 2 link buttons... the thing is, it`s working in email apps except outlook mobile app on iphone the 2 buttons is not appearing here is my link buttons html added from code behind:

```
       strHtmlButton = "<tr><i><font size=\"2\" color=\"red\">Please click on one of the below Actions to automaticallygenereate an e-mail response. Make sure that the input comments are fed within quotes.  Please do not modify any other response prompts.</font> </i><br><p> Action:<a id='lnkApprove' style='text-decoration: none;' class=\"OraLink\" href=#/\"mailto:" + objEmail.EmailFrom + "?subject=" + SubjectApp + " &amp;body=Action:%20%27Approve%27%0D%0A%0D%0AManager%20Comments:%20%27%27%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0AAPID " + PermissionID + "%0D%0A%0D%0AManagerID " + ManagerID + "%0D%0A%0D%0ANotificationId " + NotificationID + "\"><font size=\"&#45;1\"><b><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Approve\"></b></font></a><a id='lnkReject' style='text-decoration: none;' class=\"OraLink\" href=#/\"mailto:" + objEmail.EmailFrom + "?subject=" + SubjectApp + "&amp;body=Action:%20%27Reject%27%0D%0A%0D%0AManager%20Comments:%20%27%27%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0AAPID " + PermissionID + "%0D%0A%0D%0AManagerID " + ManagerID + "%0D%0A%0D%0ANotificationId " + NotificationID + "\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font size=\"2\"><b><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Reject\"></b></font></a></p>\"";
```

then am adding this string to the email body and send the email, it is not appearing in the body only outlook on iphone, i have tried to add id, target, #,#/... nothing had worked...

Comment: You failed to post your code. Without the `<a name="">`, it's really hard to determine why your code isn't working.

Comment: @gwally thank you... please add it in as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every `<a href="#linkname">linkname</a>`,

you need a corresponding `<a name="linkname"></a>` for it to link to in your code.

Good luck.